# Why is Azure Devops suddenly requesting login and password on public project Git repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a number of Git repositories in my Azure DevOps public projects and starting from yesterday, when you try to access it as an anonymous user, you are presented with Login/password prompt and you can't access it (getting 401). Previously I could send link to other people and they could browse my Git Repo without authentication.

Does this happen to anybody else? What's going on here?

Link to the one of the repos: [Link](https://dev.azure.com/tvbegovic/Portolio%20projects/_git/Adk)

Regards,
Tvrtko[image: Login&password prompt in Git repo]

Comment: Im currently having the same issue with all of my public projects; no workaround discovered yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the Policies page of the Organization Settings, please check whether "`Allow public projects`" is selected as "`On`".

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is public and it was public before. It just suddenly stopped working. Not one public projects, but all of them. I am in the process of transferring my public projects to github.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on the firefox browser. At present, this problem occurs when using the firefox browser. You can try other browsers to see if the problem still exists

Comment: Edge and Opera too.

Comment: I submitted this issue for you on the Developer Community forum. Our engineers will report this issue to the product team. Anyone with this issue can vote and follow up with this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1244051/azure-devops-suddenly-requesting-login-and-passwor.html).